# Make variable accessible through whole function

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have the following function:

```
var handsonTableHandler = (function () {

    var container = document.getElementById('WebGrid');
    var hot = "";

    var init = function () {

        //container is null here, why?
        Handsontable.renderers.registerRenderer('dataStyling', dataStyling);
        hot = new Handsontable(container, {
            startRows: 18,
            startCols: 24,
            autoWrapRow: true,
            width: 1400,
            height: 441,
            rowHeaders: true,
            colHeaders: true,
            outsideClickDeselects: false,
            search: true,
            manualColumnResize: true,
            stretchH: "all",
            afterChange: function (source, changes) {},
            cells: function (row, col, prop) {
                var cellProperties = {};
                cellProperties.renderer = "dataStyling"; // uses lookup map
                cellProperties;
            }
        });
    }
}

$(document).ready(function() {
   handsonTableHandler.init();
});
```

I want the `container` and `hot` variable to be accessible through the whole function, thus, in the init function and other functions that are defined here.

As you can see, I'm getting the element for with the Id WebGrid. But in the init-function, it's null. Why is this?

Comment: `handsonTableHandler` is self-invoking function, so there is great chance that the function is called before the element is available in the DOM.

Comment: Aha, ofc! Thank you. Any Idea how I can solve this in a nice way?

Answer (score 0):

If it was not accessable in the inner function, it would be "Undefined" instead of "Null", therefore it is accessable

you did

var container = document.getElementById('WebGrid');

but document.getElementById(...) returns Null if the element does not exist, therefore there mustnt have been an element with the id of WebGrid

Try in the console and type

```
document.getElementById('WebGrid')
```

if it returns null, then there was no element in the first place

now change your code to:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
var handsonTableHandler = (function () {

    var container = document.getElementById('WebGrid');
    var hot = "";

    var init = function () {

        //container is null here, why?
        Handsontable.renderers.registerRenderer('dataStyling', dataStyling);
        hot = new Handsontable(container, {
            startRows: 18,
            startCols: 24,
            autoWrapRow: true,
            width: 1400,
            height: 441,
            rowHeaders: true,
            colHeaders: true,
            outsideClickDeselects: false,
            search: true,
            manualColumnResize: true,
            stretchH: "all",
            afterChange: function (source, changes) {},
            cells: function (row, col, prop) {
                var cellProperties = {};
                cellProperties.renderer = "dataStyling"; // uses lookup map
                cellProperties;
            }
        });
    };
})();

handsonTableHandler.init();
```

});

Comment: If I move that code into the Init-function, It works. So It does exist a element with an Id of WebGrid.

Comment: wrap it in window.onload = function() { /* ... */ }

Answer (score 0):

to me it seems you are not running the function so the closure is never created, I added a few parenthesis, this should create the closure:

```
var handsonTableHandler = function () {

var container = document.getElementById('WebGrid');
var hot = "";

var init = function () {

    //container is null here, why?
    Handsontable.renderers.registerRenderer('dataStyling', dataStyling);
    hot = new Handsontable(container, {
        startRows: 18,
        startCols: 24,
        autoWrapRow: true,
        width: 1400,
        height: 441,
        rowHeaders: true,
        colHeaders: true,
        outsideClickDeselects: false,
        search: true,
        manualColumnResize: true,
        stretchH: "all",
        afterChange: function (source, changes) {},
        cells: function (row, col, prop) {
            var cellProperties = {};
            cellProperties.renderer = "dataStyling"; // uses lookup map
            cellProperties;
        }
    });
}

return {init: init}
};

$(document).ready(function() {
   handsonTableHandler().init();
});
```

Comment: That's not the problem. I think the problem is that the function is called before the element is available in the DOM.

Comment: can you try my latest edit?, I changed the function a little

Comment: I think you are right about the element being not available, if the closure is created when the code is parsed the DOM is not available. I changed the closure creation to the ready handler and exposed the init function using a "module pattern", that way the closure creation and init execution happen when the ready handler runs. If you need the closure, put the return value of `handsonTableHandler()` in a variable then run `init`

Answer (score 0):

The only to fix this, is to assign the DOM element to `container` in `init`, like this:

```
var handsonTableHandler = (function () {

    var container,
        hot;

    var init = function () {

        container = document.getElementById('WebGrid');

        //container is null here, why?
        Handsontable.renderers.registerRenderer('dataStyling', dataStyling);
        hot = new Handsontable(container, {
            startRows: 18,
            startCols: 24,
            autoWrapRow: true,
            width: 1400,
            height: 441,
            rowHeaders: true,
            colHeaders: true,
            outsideClickDeselects: false,
            search: true,
            manualColumnResize: true,
            stretchH: "all",
            afterChange: function (source, changes) {},
            cells: function (row, col, prop) {
                var cellProperties = {};
                cellProperties.renderer = "dataStyling"; // uses lookup map
                cellProperties;
            }
        });
    }

})()
```

Answer (score 0):

You can change you function to create handler with `new` syntax and get access to `.init` function

```
let handsonTableHandler = function () {
    this.container = document.getElementById('WebGrid');
    this.hot = "";
    this.init = function () {

        console.log('container', this.container);

        Handsontable.renderers.registerRenderer('dataStyling', dataStyling);
            this.hot = new Handsontable(this.container, {
            startRows: 18,
            startCols: 24,
            autoWrapRow: true,
            width: 1400,
            height: 441,
            rowHeaders: true,
            colHeaders: true,
            outsideClickDeselects: false,
            search: true,
            manualColumnResize: true,
            stretchH: "all",
            afterChange: function (source, changes) {},
            cells: function (row, col, prop) {
                var cellProperties = {};
                cellProperties.renderer = "dataStyling"; // uses lookup map
                cellProperties;
            }
        });
    }
}

let handler = new handsonTableHandler();

$(document).ready(function() {
   handler.init(); // output: container not null
});
```